# Shouldn't we all have the Private Beta Badge?

Tags: support, beta, badges

https://android.stackexchange.com/badges/16/beta

Or is there another party I don't know about? :P

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[beta] : **Actively** participated in the private beta.

If I recall correctly from the Web Applications stackexchange beta, these are awarded just a bit after the site goes public beta, once you have actively participated.

This site has been running nye on 3 days. It's far, *far* to early for the beta badge to be awarded.

Comment: Gotcha. This is the first private stack exchange beta I participate in.

Comment: How is "actively" defined?

Comment: @Adam According to Jeff, in reference to the StackOverflow proper beta badge, it's at least 3 bronze badges before beta is over. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/13/should-the-beta-badges-stop-being-awarded-to-users/19#19  So that's signing in (autographer for existing users), upvoting once, and say downvoting once; that's 3 bronze badges, and you'll get your silver beta badge once the beta's over.

Answer (score 1):

And now they're awarding the beta badge, after what seems like a very short private beta, at least I was notified that I had been awarded it as I logged in this morning. Presumably this means that the Private Beta is over and we're into Public Beta now.

Comment: Yes, Public Beta started yesterday (9/20).